# Gradle - don't specify version in included dependencies names

Tags: gradle

My application gets packaged as ear and I have used earlib and deploy configuration. However for all those dependencies version gets mentioned in the jar names.
For example, if I mention dependencies as below,

```
earlib 'com.xyz:abc:1.0.1'
```

In generated ear I can see jar name as abc-1.0.1.jar but I want to get it included simply as abc.jar.

Comment: Why ? Is there a specific reason ?

Comment: I want to package ear with ejb-x.jar. The manifest.mf file of ejb-x.jar having classpath entries for all jars under libs but without versions in their names. I cannot repackge ejb-x.jar with modified manifest.mf and have to use same jar. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 5):

### Declare a dependency without a version

Gradle lets you [declare a dependency without a version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#_declaring_a_dependency_without_version) but you have to define a [dependency constraint](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_constraints), which basically is the definition of your dependency version. This is commonly used in large projects:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web'
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

### Declare a dynamic version

Another option is to [declare a dynamic version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_dynamic_version) by using the plus operator. This allows you to use the latest relase of a dependency while you pack your application. Doing so is potentially dangerous since its bears the risk of breaking the application:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.+'
}
```

### Declaring a file dependency

If you don't want to rely on a binary repository at all but provide dependencies yourself, you can [declare a file dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_file_dependency), from the directories `ant`, `libs` and `tools`. This allows you to name and version dependencies as you like but you have to maintain them yourself:

```
configurations {
    antContrib
    externalLibs
    deploymentTools
}

dependencies {
    antContrib files('ant/antcontrib.jar')
    externalLibs files('libs/commons-lang.jar', 'libs/log4j.jar')
    deploymentTools fileTree(dir: 'tools', include: '*.exe')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note** I recommend against removing the versions as they are important diagnostic information when the application doesn't work.

The `ear` task is an instance of the [`Ear`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ear.Ear.html) task type, which in turn is basically a specialised form of the standard [`Zip`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) task type. All archiving tasks allow you to rename files as they are packed.

For example, the following might work:

```
ear {
    rename '(.+)-[^-].+(\\.jar)', '$1$2'
    lib {
        rename '(.+)-[^-].+(\\.jar)', '$1$2'
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend that you check out the new user manual chapter on [*Working with files*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:renaming_files_example) for more information about copying and archiving files. Hopefully I'll remember to update this answer with the non-release-candidate link once Gradle 4.7 is out.

Also, if you have any feedback on that chapter let me know.

**EDIT** Based on OP's feedback, I discovered that the `Ear` task uses a child copy specification for the JARs in the `earlib` configuration. Child specifications are independent of both the main one and other child specs, so the main `rename()` doesn't apply to the `earlib` files. That's why we add a `rename()` via the `lib {}` block.

Comment: thanks. it is working for jars having 'deploy' configuration but not for 'earlib' i.e jars exist in 'libs' of ear. I tried with 'rootSpec.allSpecs*.rename(…)' but seems its works only with gradle 1.7 or lower.

Comment: Uggh. This is a peculiarity of the `Ear` task. The libs are handled by what is known as a child spec, which has its own configuration. The top-level `rename()` does not apply to it. I'll update the answer with what I think is the solution, but I can't easily test it. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It's not working as I would expect. I don't really understand why it works for the main spec — with the `deploy` dependencies — but not the `lib` spec. I'm asking, but I'm not hopeful of an answer I'm afraid.